# Merge Dataframes based off Key and Comparison of Separate Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm comparing data pulled from SQL to try and track patients that were transferred out of a hospital, and see if they were admitted into another hospital in the system, or if they "leaked" out. I'm tracking them based off a medical key that is unique to them, and remains the same in the system regardless of hospital or separate admissions. As such, in both dataframes, the 'key' can appear multiple times, for multiple visits within the timeframe. What I want to do is match the keys in the first dataframe, which contains data of patients that discharged as "transfer to another hospital" for a specific hospital, to the keys of a separate dataframe, which contains data for all the hospitals in the same system as the original hospital, but I only want to match the lines together if the discharge datetime from the first dataframe is within 24 hours before the admission datetime from the second.

For obvious reasons, these are fake dataframes, but dataframe A would look like this:

```
| Row | Patient Key | Source Hospital | Source Discharge Datetime |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | | -------- |
| 1   | A123   | A   | 1-1-23 01:00:00   |
| 2   | A123   | A   | 2-3-23 10:00:00   |
| 3   | A321   | A   | 3-2-32 11:00:00   |
| 4   | A213   | A   | 2-3-23 13:00:00   |
| 5   | A321   | A   | 3-30-32 12:00:00   |
```

Dataframe B would look like this:

```
| Patient Key | Destination Hospital | Destination Admit Datetime |
| -------- | -------- | | -------- |
| A123   | C   | 1-1-23 03:00:00   |
| A123   | C   | 2-5-23 10:00:00   |
| A321   | B   | 3-2-32 11:45:00   |
| A213   | C   | 2-3-23 13:59:00   |
| A321   | B   | 3-5-32 12:00:00   |
```

And the resulting Dataframe would be:

```
| Row | Patient Key | Source Hospital | Source Discharge Datetime |  Destination Hospital | Destination Admit Datetime |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | | -------- |  -------- | | -------- |
| 1   | A123   | A   | 1-1-23 01:00:00   | C   | 1-1-23 03:00:00   |
| 2   | A123   | A   | 2-3-23 10:00:00   | NULL   | NULL   |
| 3   | A321   | A   | 3-2-32 11:00:00   | B   | 3-2-32 11:45:00   |
| 4   | A213   | A   | 2-3-23 13:00:00   | C   | 2-3-23 13:59:00   |
| 5   | A321   | A   | 3-30-32 12:00:00   | NULL   | NULL   |
```

Because Rows 2 and 5 in Database A do not have any matching rows within 24 hours in Database B, the rows are left as "NULL" for Destination hospital and admit datetime, as they have no visits in other hospitals that could correspond to the "transfered to another hospital" discharged visit in Dataframe A. The point of this analysis is to see what % of all the rows end up being NULLS, so we know which patients "leaked" out of our hospital system.

I know how I could hard code this in Jupyter, but I was wondering if there were any easier way I missed in research and digging? Or if I'm just gonna have to suck it up and hardcode a merge based off these conditions. I haven't been able to find anything in my digging, but it's entirely possible there's a method that I'm missing somewhere or somehow, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a nearest-key merge: [`.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(
   left  = df_a.sort_values("Source Discharge Datetime"), 
   right = df_b.sort_values("Destination Admit Datetime"),
   by = "Patient Key", 
   left_on = "Source Discharge Datetime", 
   right_on = "Destination Admit Datetime",
   direction = "nearest",
   tolerance = pd.Timedelta(days=1)
)
```

```
   Row Patient Key Source Hospital Source Discharge Datetime Destination Hospital Destination Admit Datetime
0    1        A123               A       2023-01-01 01:00:00                    C        2023-01-01 03:00:00
1    2        A123               A       2023-02-03 10:00:00                  NaN                        NaT
2    4        A213               A       2023-02-03 13:00:00                    C        2023-02-03 13:59:00
3    3        A321               A       2023-03-02 11:00:00                    B        2023-03-02 11:45:00
4    5        A321               A       2023-03-30 12:00:00                  NaN                        NaT
```